# Push Notification in Laravel 4

Tags: php, laravel-4

I am using Laravel 4 and I have a push notification system . 
I had research and found a library support to :
https://github.com/davibennun/laravel-push-notification

I have configured as guide and when I run my routes as below :

```
Route::get('/push',function(){
$push = new \Davibennun\LaravelPushNotification\PushNotification();
$push->app('appNameAndroid')->to('My-device-token')->sent('my message'); }
```

It displayed an error :

> Zend \ Http \ Client \ Adapter \ Exception \ RuntimeException 
>   Unable to enable crypto on TCP connection android.googleapis.com: make sure the "sslcafile" or "sslcapath" option are properly set for the environment.

I thought the cause is my openssl problem (I am using LAMP in Ubuntu ) and try to all way I found on internet , even I also tried to run that script on Windows (XAMPP) and it's still not works .

any ideal ?

**Update:**
I had to go to **vendor/zendframework/zend-http/Zend/Http/Client/Adapter/Socket.php** and change its config['sslverifypeer'] to "null" and it's worked ! And it's only in local server, in live server , default setting could run perfectly !

Comment: Yhey seem to be an issue for this on the github zend repository.  https://github.com/zendframework/ZendGData/issues/7. For your other question, please open a new question. Only one question per post

Comment: looks like system try to make ssl connection using certificate but doesn't have a CA file for ssl authority

Comment: I have setup SSL followed link : http://beginlinux.com/blog/2009/01/ssl-on-ubuntu-810-apache2/ and got the same error .